# Can I get back an uninsured car?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

My friend destroyed my car and I don't have insurance on it. Can I get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, from my experience, you cannot. You just have to buy another. Next time, you may want to get insurance to avoid losing your car.